# Compile OpenVPN or SoftEther as DLL for use in C# WPF

Tags: c#, dll, build, integration, openvpn

I am trying to make a front end for my friends VPN Server hosting company. I have made most of the application with WPF and it is working as a standalone product. It downloads the server list from his website with JSON and populates the selection contents, does ping tests, and so on.

Now I am at the stage where I need to actually make it do something - my options seem to be OpenVPN or SoftEther.

I have tried to build OpenVPN as they recommend with VS2010, and SoftEther with 2008 Professional. I am really struggling to get a working build out of either, when their websites say it should just work if dependancys are met.

My understanding here is that I need to build the client from either of these 2 options as a dll, which I can then use as a lib into my C# Application and call any public facing connect functions and pass in the username and password entered in my GUI.

Am I on the right chain of thought? Has anybody out there successfully integrated OpenVPN or SoftEther into their own products?

I should mention I am totally lost with OpenVPN, but SoftEther builds for the most part but the installer is half empty and the drivers wont install for the virtual adapter either. Of course I can install them using the prebuilt binarys on the respective websites.

Comment: have you build an OpenVPN.dll finally?

Comment: No, I scrapped it in the end.

Comment: Do you know any OpenVpn wrapper for usage via .Net (c#)?